# Error updating GraphLab Create dependencies: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_dependencies'

Tags: graphlab

Upon "import graphlab" the following occurs:

```
ACTION REQUIRED: Dependencies libstdc++-6.dll and libgcc_s_seh-1.dll not found.

1. Ensure user account has write permission to C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\graphlab
2. Run graphlab.get_dependencies() to download and install them.
3. Restart Python and import graphlab again.

By running the above function, you agree to the following licenses.

* libstdc++: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/license.html
* xz: http://git.tukaani.org/?p=xz.git;a=blob;f=COPYING
```

I tried running "graphlab.get_dependencies()", but got the following:

```
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-3-9e64085fb919> in <module>()

----> 1 graphlab.get_dependencies()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_dependencies'
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the dependencies error in both IPython and on the python command line. I didn't have any luck installing through the GraphLab Create launcher.  I had to run the following command to fix the installation (my environment name is "gl-env".  Change this name to your environment):

```
activate gl-env

python -m ipykernel install --user --name gl-env --display-name "Python (gl-env)
```

Then I opened a python command line and ran:

```
import graphlab
graphlab.get_dependencies()
```

Note when running this last import command, I get the error in the OP, however after running the .get_dependencies() method it finds the module and installs the necessary dependencies.  Subsequent calls to "import graphlab" succeed after this.

Answer (score 0):

Got a response back from Turi about the issue. The following resolved the problem:

"This error is most likely due to a corrupt installation of GraphLab Create due to other Python processes, such as iPython Notebooks, running in the background while GLC is trying to install. To resolve the issue, please do the following:

1. Completely shut down and reboot your system. Do no start any applications or processes that use Python or GraphLab Create.
2. Try installing GraphLab Create again, preferably using the GraphLab Create Launcher: https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create.html"