# Module object has no attribute SFrame when running .exe

Tags: python, anaconda, data-science, graphlab

I have graphlab installed using Anaconda and a gl-env and I built a program with it that works without errors. I'm using python 2.7.15, pip 9.0.1 and Windows 7.

I've used pyinstaller to convert the file to an .exe but when running the .exe I get an error about a line of code in my program.

This the error I get when running the program .exe:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9I64.jpg]

This is the first section of my code where the error is occuring at line 31 but Im not sure whats wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
import graphlab
import graphlab as gl 
import graphlab as gl
import sqlite3

# sql database for stored user recommendations
MusicData = sqlite3.connect("D:\lastfm-dataset-360K\msd.sqlite3")

plays_df = graphlab.SFrame.from_sql(MusicData, "SELECT * FROM train where plays >=1")
songs_df = graphlab.SFrame.from_sql(MusicData, "SELECT * FROM song")

users = graphlab.SArray(songs_set['userID'].unique().head(100))

recs_model = graphlab.recommender.ranking_factorization_recommender.create(plays_df, user_id = "userID", item_id = "songID", target = "plays")
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128663/error-while-using-graphlab-create-jupyter and also you don't need three graphlab statements