# graphlab SFrame.read_csv() error

Tags: python, csv, graphlab

I’ve come across an issue testing out my graphlab installation using code from this [link](https://turi.com/learn/gallery/notebooks/getting_started_with_graphlab_create.html).  I use Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) and when I run these first few lines:

`import graphlab as gl`

`gl.canvas.set_target('ipynb') # use IPython Notebook output for GraphLab Canvas`

`vertices = gl.SFrame.read_csv('https://static.turi.com/datasets/bond/bond_vertices.csv')`

I get this error at the end of the stack trace:

`IOError: Cannot open https://static.turi.com/datasets/bond/bond_vertices.csv: unspecified iostream_category error: unspecified iostream_category error`

I've tried reinstalling, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048111/error-updating-graphlab-create-dependencies-attributeerror-module-object-has) but after following the directions and trying to run graphlab.get_dependencies(), I get this error:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_dependencies'`

This isn't an issue with the Windows side of my computer.

If I download the reference .csv files and open them locally, there is no error.  Does anyone have any suggestions on this?